# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'detachEvent' - on YouTube player close

Tags: backbone.js, youtube-api

I keep getting the following error whenever I close a Backbone view, from the error it seems like the YouTube player is not closing nicely:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'detachEvent' html5player-vfl_ymO4Z.js:73

(anonymous function) html5player-vfl_ymO4Z.js:73
og.(anonymous function).d html5player-vfl_ymO4Z.js:22
cl html5player-vfl_ymO4Z.js:73
hl html5player-vfl_ymO4Z.js:74
P.G html5player-vfl_ymO4Z.js:616
(anonymous function) html5player-vfl_ymO4Z.js:75
ul html5player-vfl_ymO4Z.js:75
(anonymous function) html5player-vfl_ymO4Z.js:18
sl.(anonymous function).G html5player-vfl_ymO4Z.js:75
P.G html5player-vfl_ymO4Z.js:732
(anonymous function) html5player-vfl_ymO4Z.js:75
P.Jr html5player-vfl_ymO4Z.js:85
dn www-embed-player-vflX1WAR4.js:207
M.I www-embed-player-vflX1WAR4.js:208
gf.(anonymous function).dispose www-embed-player-vflX1WAR4.js:29
Ym www-embed-player-vflX1WAR4.js:195
M.Fd www-embed-player-vflX1WAR4.js:207
(anonymous function) www-embed-player-vflX1WAR4.js:230
h www-embed-player-vflX1WAR4.js:28
jQuery.fn.extend.remove jquery.js:6117
_.extend.remove backbone.js:1023
Marionette.View.Backbone.View.extend.close backbone.marionette.js:924
Marionette.ItemView.Marionette.View.extend.close
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I am also having this issue with the Youtube iFrame player using HTML5. Digging into it today to see if I can find a fix.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in the Youtube js: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4741

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this event handling code for ender break when I try to clean it up some?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149565/why-does-this-event-handling-code-for-ender-break-when-i-try-to-clean-it-up-some)